# SSLSocket: why do we need to do the handshake before accessing the server certificate?

Tags: java, ssl

I'm connecting through a SSLSocket to a distant host which is using a certificate for the handshake. As we don't use the default JVM truststore with all the certificate authorities, i need to add the remote host certificates to my truststore.

How can i get the certificates that i should trust from the SSLSocket? It seems do retrieve them i need to use the SSLSession which seems to require the handshake.
Why do we need to perform the handshake to be able to retrieve the certificates?

Is there any tool that permits to extract the remote host certificates used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you shouldn't get the certificate you should trust from an `SSLSocket`, instead, it should be a configured setting that you obtained independently, as a reference for what you want to trust.

What you seem to want to do is to get the certificate for the first connection, hoping that that connection wasn't intercepted, and then use this as a reference for subsequent connections (similar to what's commonly done with SSH, when you don't necessarily know the server key's fingerprint on the first connection, but check that you get the same later).

Security-wise, this isn't ideal because the initial connection may be intercepted by a MITM attacker (which would make all subsequent connections vulnerable), but that's certainly a way to mitigate the risks. Ideally, you should compare that certificate with a known reference you've obtained some other way.

You can access the remote certificate during the handshake using a custom `X509TrustManager` (or you can disable trust verification with it and get the certificate later), which you can then use to initialise an `SSLContext`, from which you can obtain your `SSLSocketFactory`. It's generally a bad idea to disable trust verification in a trust manager (since it opens the connection to MITM attacks), but it can be acceptable for this purpose. You may be interested in the [`InstallCert`](http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java) utility, which should do more or less what you're after.

> Why do we need to do the handshake before accessing the server
> certificate?

This is done during the handshake, because the purpose of the SSL/TLS socket API is to provide the application layer with a socket it can consider secure and use more or less as a normal socket at that stage. Typically, for most uses of JSSE (or generally other SSL/TLS stacks), as an application developer using that stack, you don't want to have to do the verification explicitly. Checking the certificate during the handshake is also recommended as part of the [TLS specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-7.4.5):

> Upon receipt of the server hello done message, the client SHOULD
> verify that the server provided a valid certificate, if required
> and check that the server hello parameters are acceptable.

Comment: I finally found in the documentation the certificate authority to add to my truststore. But sometimes it's kind of hard to find it in the documentation, and just wanted to know how to retrieve that certificate when it's not explicitly mentionned in the remote host documentation. Thanks

Comment: +1 Accepting trust material over the connection you are trying to establish trust over doesn't make any sense. It has to be an offline process.

Answer (score 4):

Actually certificates are presented during the handshake, so that the server can identify itself, and the eventually the same for the client.

When you do:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
[...]
SavingTrustManager tm = new SavingTrustManager(defaultTrustManager);
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);
try {
    socket.startHandshake();
    socket.close();
} catch (SSLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

if you don't get an exception on startHandshake(), it means the certificate is already trusted for some reason (directly present in keystore, of signed by a trusted entity).

Exception occurred or not, you can access the downloaded chain:

```
X509Certificate[] chain = tm.chain;
if (chain == null) {
   // error in downloading certificate chain
   return;
}

// loop through chain
for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
    X509Certificate cert = chain[i];
    [....]
}
```

With the X509Certificate object instance, you can actually update your k-ieth keystore:

```
X509Certificate cert = chain[k];
String alias = host + "-" + (k + 1);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
[...]
ks.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("jssecacerts");
ks.store(out, passphrase);
out.close();
```

Look [here](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/ssl-download-certificate-chain) for the complete sample.

Alternatively, another maybe safer way to download the certificate for a server you trust, is using openssl command:

```
# openssl s_client -showcerts -connect $SERVER:$PORT  2>&1 | \
      sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' >/tmp/$SERVERNAME.cert
```

then import it as usual with `keytool`.

Comment: I must admit I find the `openssl s_client` method quicker when I need that sort of thing too.

Comment: The provided link works but there is no visible content / full sample. Would you mind posting the complete sample?